# Update a QTableView entirely when data has changed

Tags: pyqt, qtableview, qabstractitemmodel

I have a `QTableView` using a custom `QAbstractTableModel`, and I would like to update the entire table view when the underlying data has change.

Note that a data change can be anything:

- rows inserted
- rows deleted
- existing rows changed
- all of the above

All existing solutions I found involve using `insertRows` / `deleteRows`, but AFAIK that would require me to do some bookkeeping of my data to find out exactly which existing rows changed, and which rows where added in between existing rows.

Is there a way to just tell the view that the entire model may have changed and that it should update everything?

Here is a code example to demonstrate my problem:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MyTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._data = [
            ("spam", "spam", "spam", "spam"),
            ("spam", "spam", "spam", "spam"),
            ("spam", "spam", "spam", "spam"),
        ]

    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return f"Foo {section + 1}"

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 4

    def refresh_data(self):
        self._data.insert(0, ("ham", "ham", "ham", "ham"))
        topLeft = self.createIndex(0, 0)
        bottomRight = self.createIndex(self.rowCount(), self.columnCount())
        self.dataChanged.emit(topLeft, bottomRight)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        layout.addWidget(self.table)

        self.model = MyTableModel()
        self.table.setModel(self.model)

        update_data_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Update data")
        update_data_button.clicked.connect(self.model.refresh_data)
        layout.addWidget(update_data_button)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

When I click the `update_data_button`, I see how the new data is inserted at the beginning, but the number of rows in the view is not updated, so the last rows are just dropped.

[image: Initial data]

[image: View after one click (note that the last row is dropped)]

In the future I want to implement a more fine grained updating of my data, by inserting/deleting rows as needed, but I'm not there yet. I have to assume that my data source can change any cell anywhere in the data and add/remove rows anywhere, without being able to easily find where the change happened (short of having to keep a copy of the data and iterate through both the old and new data structures to find the differences).

Comment: emit `layoutChanged` signal. It's the quick 'n dirty way to get the view to update, but that's what you're asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`dataChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) is not appropriate for this purpose: it only tells any connected view that the data of the currently *known* items has changed. The item view will then assume that the model size and hierarchy is still the same and cannot realize that there are less or more rows or columns. In fact, just calling `dataChanged` when the model size has changed could potentially result in a raised exception.

Basically speaking, it's just like notifying that a value in a list item has been changed: the assumption is that the list still has the same item count.

A common way to work around this is to emit the [`layoutChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#layoutChanged) signal, but that's not very appropriate: the concept of *layout* normally indicates that the basic structure (row and column count) remains unchanged. That signal should only be used when the actual layout has changed: for instance, when the model has been sorted.

While Qt item views are normally able to "work around" this approach, it's not consistent nor reliable. Views have fail safe systems that automatically ignore some aspects when the model is not consistent with what they "previously" knew, but trusting them is just an educated guess at least, and, formally, an unreliable assumption.

Whenever the model radically changes (row/column size and item data are invalidated), the more appropriate solution is to rely on the "model reset" concept.

The basic solution is to just emit the [`modelReset`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#modelReset) signal, but since item views also consider persistent indexes and their selection model, a more correct way is to properly call the `begin/end` functions QAbstractItemModel provides. In this case, the order is:

1. call [`beginResetModel()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginResetModel);
2. change the underlying data;
3. call [`endResetModel()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#endResetModel)

Using the functions above will also prepare you to further changes in the model: whenever rows or columns are added, removed or moved, you need to call the appropriate `begin*()` function, then apply the required changes, and finally call the related `end*()` function.

This ensures that the connected views keep their status properly updated, considering index order, selections, and even using some important performance optimization that are necessary for large or complex models.

Comment: The problem to use modelReset is that "When a model is reset it means that any previous data reported from the model is now invalid and has to be queried for again. **This also means that the current item and any selected items will become invalid**." So I'd rather use layoutChanged() to avoid the problem though its name doesn't actually match its functionality - it is also emitted when "the structure of the underlying data changes".

Comment: @iMath Your last quote of the documentation is a bit vague and misleading. In fact, not only it fails to highlight the fact that `layoutChanged` should **always** be preceded by a `layoutAboutToBeChanged` (failing to do so may cause severe issues, especially if using proxy models), but it's also ambiguous, and it's all better explained in the expanded `layoutChanged` documentation; those signals are intended for changes in the *layout of items exposed by the model*, not the *shape* (the row/column count), which should remain identical. They give the example of sorting, but another simple »

Comment: @iMath » case is when columns or rows may be moved (not by moving sections in headers) or when *moving* an arbitrary group of items while preserving the others. The difference may be subtle, but it's important: layout changes do not (normally) refer to insertion or removal of rows/columns, even though it may be perceived as such when moving items to a different parent. I suggested `modelReset` because the OP asked for a generic solution, but while it's true that `modelReset` shouldn't be used when only part of the model changes, it's also true that any case involving shape/size changes in »

Comment: @iMath » the whole model should only use the begin/end inserted/remove row/column functions or signals, and using the layout change ones is *wrong*, because they only notify that the order of items has changed, not that items may have been added or deleted. That's also why the docs suggest to use the moveColumns/Rows functions or signals as an alternative to layoutChanges, but do *not* do so for the insert/remove cases.

Comment: As I tested , layoutChanged does notify  items that have been added or deleted

Comment: It ***may*** cause querying again for row and column count, but that's just an assumption that may not be respected by connected objects such as views, proxies and, most importantly, custom connections that *do* require specific signals. You may use it for generic usage as long as you are **fully aware** about its consequences, but suggesting it for any model change is still inappropriate, as it's just *wrong*.